# How to color GeoTIFF if its values are from -1 to 1?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

1. There is a GeoTIFF, 1 channel. How do I color it? Namely, values that were from -1 to 0.02 color in red, from 0.02 to 0.5 color in yellow, and values that are greater than 0.5 color in green.

[image]

GeoTIFF shows the calculated NDVI by fields.

I read about GDAL COLOR TABLE, but you can only put integer values there

2. How can I then apply a vector to this colored GEOTIFF?

[image]

Here's how it should end up

I need to do this in Python.

## UPD

I uploaded a pseudo color:

```
INTERPOLATION:DISCRETE
0.02,252,0,4,255,<=0.02
0.5,200,180,0,255,0.02 - 0.05
1,2,177,26,255,0.5 - 1
```

How to add to GeoTIFF from Python?

Comment: With PyQGIS, it could be used code in my answer. It has your code colors, your limits of classes and DISCRETE condition for interpolating colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyQGIS, it could be used following code. It has your code colors, your limits of classes and DISCRETE condition for interpolating colors.

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()

colDic = {'red':QColor(252,0,4,255), 'yellow':QColor(200,180,0,255),'green':QColor(2,177,26,255)}

valueList =[0.02, 0.5, 1] #limits of classes

lst = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0], colDic['red'], '<=0.02'),

        QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1], colDic['yellow'], '0.02 - 0.05'),

        QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2], colDic['green'], '0.5 - 1')]

myRasterShader = QgsRasterShader()

myColorRamp = QgsColorRampShader()

myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(lst)

myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Discrete)

myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

myPseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer( layer.dataProvider(),
                                                     layer.type(),
                                                     myRasterShader)

layer.setRenderer(myPseudoRenderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

After running above code, in Python Console of QGIS 3, I got following result with a NDVI raster layer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the solution is great, but it would be great if it were using GDAL.